# running shell command in python

Tags: python, shell, openvpn

I have this simple code for running shell scripts and it sometimes work, sometimes not.If not working console log is:

> Please edit the vars script to reflect your configuration,   then
>   source it with "source ./vars".   Next, to start with a fresh PKI
>   configuration and to delete any   previous certificates and keys, run
>   "./clean-all".   Finally, you can run this tool (pkitool) to build
>   certificates/keys.

It is strange for me because when I run commands in console they work as should

```
def cmds(*args):

    cd1 = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && source ./vars"
    cd2 = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && ./clean-all"
    cd3  = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' | ./build-ca"

    runcd1 = subprocess.Popen(cd1, shell=True)
    runcd2 = subprocess.Popen(cd2 , shell=True)
    runcd3 = subprocess.Popen(cd3 , shell=True)

    return (runcd1, runcd2, runcd3)
```

I've changed like this:

```
def pass3Cmds(*args):
    commands = "cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa && source ./vars && ./clean-all &&   printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' | ./build-ca"
    runCommands = subprocess.Popen(commands, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    return (runCommands)
```

but console writes down:

> source: not found

Comment: You don't need a subprocess to change the directory, you cam also pass the cwd to the subprocess cwd=path, if one relies in the other being complete you might also have more problems as Popen does not wait

Comment: Add `runcd.communicate()` after each `Popen`-instantiation. Otherwise you have no guarantee that the previous commands have completed before calling the next command.

Comment: addind `.communicate()` after first and second lines changed nothing...

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the three commands into one.

The "source ./vars" only affects the shell from which it's run. When you use three separate Popen commands, you're getting three separate shells.

Run all the commands in one Popen with &&s between them.

The reason this works "sometimes" as written is that you're sometimes running python in a shell where you already sourced the vars script.

Comment: Thanks ,Borealid ,seem it should work but still not ( I've edited, please see above)

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko Your `pass3Cmds`  function should work, assuming your shell is bash. You can remove the `cd` and use the `cwd` argument to `Popen` as suggested in another comment, but beyond that there's nothing wrong with this code that I can see.